# How can I see app reviews in itunesconnect from all store fronts?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Itunesconnect says my app has "6 reviews" (woohoo!), but I can't see them. It says "No reviews for this store front". I assume (after some googling) that the store front is associated with country. I tried changing from United States in the dropdown at the top, but United States is the only choice.  I'd like to see all reviews regardless of store front/language. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it just mean you have 6 people rated your app but no one has written any reviews. But I don't think it is possible to see reviews from all regions.

It could also be possible that review takes time to show up. [source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201991)

> Your review might need to be approved before it's published, so it might not appear immediately.

Comment: Could be that rating=review, but it's very confusing since it says 6 ratings at top, then 6 reviews below, so it implies they are separate things.